# Regex to select lines starting with whitespaces after a certain string

Tags: javascript, regex

So I am trying to create a regex to replace lines after a string.

var code =

```
if('this' == 'this')
    alert('hello');
    alert('hello');
```

*Above is the code in the variable. It is taken from a certain place, and not defined in js file, so excuse me if I did not define it as a variable properly (that is the example of the code I have in the variable).*

Beneath is the regex that I need to work, with an explanation. But it doesnt work. And I cant figure out how to make it work.

```
code = code.replace /(^\s*)(if\(.*$)(\n|$)(^$1\s.*\n|$|\z)/gm, '$1$2 {$3$4\n$1}'
```

So the RegEx goes like this:

1. `(^\s*)` - from the beginning of the line, get all whitespaces(usually tabs)
2. `(if\(.*$)` - get content from the beginning of the 'if' statement, till the end of the line
3. `(\n|$)` - get the end of the line
4. `(^$1\s.*\n|$|\z)` - get all the lines, that follow the line with the if statement, that have the same amount of white spaces as in (^\s*) (defined by $1), plus one more whitespace. Then select the rest of the line with the end of the line or of the variable.

In the `'$1$2 {$3$4\n$1}'` - first come the white spaces ($1) and the if statement ($2), then ' {', than the line break ($3), then the next lines ($4), then new line + same amount of whitespaces as in the beginning, then '}' ($5)

**Edited:**

For some reason this code is not working and does not select **anything after the if statement line**. I was experimenting with other combinations, and the best I got is to select just one line after the if statement (not more, than one line).

The mistake is somewhere in the 4th section ($4).
The problem is to select all of the needed content after the if statement.

**Expected results:**

```
if('this' == 'this') {
    alert('hello');
    alert('hello');
}
```

Comment: String examples?

Comment: @S.Jovan I wrote in the beginning `code = ` then the example of code to be processed

Comment: Do you want to enclose both the lines below the if statement within `{` `}`?

Comment: Just note that inline backreferences have `\1` like syntax, not `$1` (you have `$1` inside the regex pattern, see `/(^\s*)(if\(.*$)(\n|$)(^$1\s.*\n|$|\z)/gm`). Another point is that parsing code with regex is not safe.

Comment: @Gurman I want to enclose all of the lines after the if statement, that have the same amount of whitespaces as the if statement has + 1 whitespace. In this example it is only two lines.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew $1 worked pergectly with other replacements + it works with the if statement. Also if not regex, what else?

Comment: You have `$1` inside the regex pattern. And you will have to write your own parser or use an existing one, like [Esprima](http://esprima.org/). Regex won't work in 100% cases.

Comment: Can you post the expected results? The goal is important to now or else how do we know if we are correct?

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is your friend

Comment: @zer00ne Posted them.

Comment: @Mee Ok, see my answer the `s` flag made it quite easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(^\s+)(if\(.*)([\n]+\1(\s+.*)+)
```

Replace the match with:

```
\1\2{\3\n\1}
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0IY8v7/3)**

**Explanation:**

- `(^\s+)` - matches 1+ occurrences of whitespaces at the beggining of each line and capture it in group 1
- `(if\(.*)` - matches `if(` followed by 0+ occurrences of any character except a newline and stores the whole thing in group 2
- `([\n]+\1(\s+.*)+)` - capture this whole as group 3. See explanation below

  - `[\n]+` - matches 1+ occurrences of a newline. This is right after the `if` statement.
  - `\1` - matches whatever was captured in group 1.(to reach the same indentation level of the `if` statement)
  - `\s+` - to match 1+ spaces so as to make sure that we are moving 1-level right to the indentation of `if` statement(I hope that makes sense)
  - `.*` - to match 0+ occurrences of any character except a newline
  - `(\s+.*)+` - 1+ occurrences of above 2 sub-sequences

Comment: Thank you, and this looks really great, and on your 'Demo' it seems to work. But my script isnt working. I am using CoffeeScript, and the Gulp just breaks, because of the `\1\2{\3\n\1}` in replacement. I tried to replace `\1` to `$1`, and to walk around to JS file (without coffee), but it does not work. Brackets dont appear... Trying to figure it out

Comment: Awsome, thanks. Just needed to change (^\s+) to (^\s*), as white spaces before 'if' are optional. Thank you. And thanks for telling about the website to test regexes. Didnt know of it.